# in memory mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification and save memory leak

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I has some increasing in memory size of my application (osx 10.8.3) when i'm using in memory type nsmanagedobjectcontext:

Bellow is a top 2 functions by instruments.

I do clearing of that in memory issues, but leak is still keep. Can u please suggest any way where i have to looking for?

here is a top responsible callers (all for CoreData):

```
CoreData    -[_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet willRead] 
CoreData        _PFAllocateObject
CoreData        [NSDictionaryStoreMap _nodeFromObject:objectIDMap:]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apologies as this is unrelated to your question, but did you know that  you can force the method to be called in the main thread by using `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:_cmd withObject:<#parameter#> waitUntilDone:YES];` rather than explicitly stating the method in the call?  It will save you some typing and help avoid mistakes.

Comment: this is bcs i need to do it in main thread and if i'm not in main thread i starting selector from main thread.

Comment: You miss my point; my suggestion will do the same *without* having to explicitly state the `@selector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bcs Marcus don't write any example, i want to try to answer at my own question:
Memory leaks gone as i see. But i got more pain, lets describe step by step.

After investigating around experience across internet resources i was choose scheme:
I have two inMemory main MOCs with different persistent store coordinates.

- Main MOC for dynamic info (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)
- Main MOC for static info (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)

It's bcs i have very high load to first moc and not too much to second (but there is large data)

Then, all created threads create own MOCs (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType), make parent according type and do what they can do. It's multithread server, so i can delete object from another thread.

this is a code for save:

```
-(void) finalSaveMocInMemoryForDynamicInformation;
{
    [_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation performBlock:^{
        @try {
            if ([_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation hasChanges]) {
                NSError *error;
                AppDelegate *delegateMain = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                if ([_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation save:&error])
                {
                    [delegateMain.managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation performBlock:^{
                        @try {
                            if ([delegateMain.managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation hasChanges]) {
                                NSError *error;
                                if (![delegateMain.managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation save:&error])
                                {
                                    [self logError:error forDelegate:delegateMain];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @catch (NSException *exception) {
                            NSLog(@"SIP CONTROLLER:ERROR:%@:%@ exception->%@ inside managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation",[self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),exception);
                            return ;
                        }

                    }];
                } else [self logError:error forDelegate:delegateMain];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"SIP CONTROLLER:ERROR:%@:%@ exception->%@ inside _mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation",[self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),exception);
            return ;
        }

    }];
}
```

Model is worked correctly before on old scheme.
When i starting using server in production, i got tonns of errors while save, where is talking that can't delete non-existing object (sub-objects from three). Looks like core data don't understand that objects have temporary ID and try to remove them in cascade mode.

I was thinking that too much error while save not good idea and i try to fix it by using obtainPermanentID: function. Errors go out, but i got crash report, which start time-to-time, described here:

[core data child/parent save exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024859/core-data-child-parent-save-exception)

Then, i was removed all obtainPermanentID's and return back to clear code. But now instead previous crashes got a crash:

```
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff867bcbd1 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 1297
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff867c3268 CFBasicHashAddValue + 3176
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff867d8ba9 CFSetAddValue + 121
3   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff89f15986 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _insertObjectWithGlobalID:globalID:] + 182
4   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff89f15850 -[NSManagedObjectContext insertObject:] + 144
5   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff89eec056 -[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] + 534
6   com.apple.CoreData              0x00007fff89f15722 +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 178
7   com.yourcompany.callsfreecalls  0x000000010b3a87f9 -[SipController packetForData:forSocketData:isUDPsocket:forIncomingLeg:] + 23545

Crashed Thread:  15  Dispatch queue: socketIncomingLegQueue

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfffffffffffffff8

VM Regions Near 0xfffffffffffffff8:
--> shared memory          00007fffffffe000-00007ffffffff000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=SHM
```

Both crashes is going inside core data, and that mean that i can't do nothing with that. It's can't debugged by CORE_DATA_DEBUG bcs loading too high, and i can't @catch exception bcs it's inside apple libs, while they do execute requests). Apple bug report'ing doesn't answer for months.
Here is two things which can be. First - i don't understand something in new model (maybe main MOCs must be in NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType and child MOC must be in NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, or i need to save or merge something (but apple told that no), or i need to moving all issues of core objects like insert new objects fetch requests e.t.c inside ^performBlock of according MOCs e.t.c e.t.c e.t.c) .
Second - new core data model is too buggy and i need move it out and do own model with objects.

Reasonable suggestions and experience sharing will be appreciated. I will adding more information while i will investigate all ways to avoid found bugs.

**UPDATE**

For now, good news for me (but probably not good for apple) Error was fixed by very strange reason.
In my model i has that scheme:
ActiveSession ----(to-one) ---> ActiveSessionIncomingLeg --(to-many)-> ActivePacket
              ----(to-one) ---> ActiveSessionOutgoingLeg --(to-many)-> ActivePacket
The reason for using to-one relationship is i have only one leg incoming and outgoing. It worked fine before child/parent scheme and got me a easy access to attributes like:

```
NSOrderedSet *set = incomingLeg.activeSession.activeSessionOutgoingLeg.activePacket;
```

Just to check, i was change to-one relationship to particular (to-many). And WOW - crash was done out.
Hope it can helps to community. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

How big is this leak? How frequent? If the leak is inside of Core Data (as it appears) and it is small, there may be nothing you can do about it other than filing a radar.

I would suggest that you switch over to using the parent/child context design instead of using the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` as that is faster, doesn't block the main thread and probably will solve your memory leak to boot.

### Update

300Mb in allocation is not a leak.  Allocation is how much memory your application is using when it is running.  If your leak is tiny (which it appears is the case) and it is inside of Core Data itself, there is nothing to be done about it as it is not worth chasing down.

Comment: hi Marcus, nice to hear u again. i got around 300M-500M per day. tnx for suggest is parent/child working well now? bcs i was not sure that this is stable now. Can u suggest complex code snippet (probably post here) which u are using and it working well for u on osx with big data volumes.

Comment: I am using it in many applications, none of which I can post here because they are not open source projects. It is working well with the current releases of iOS and OS X.  What is 300M-500M?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Can you show the leaks display instead of the allocation display in instruments?  I suspect you are allocating 300Mb not leaking 300Mb.

Comment: sorry for mistake, i mean allocation of course. leaks display show nothing

Comment: may i ask u to write here a code snippet for osx, which support good loading osx using parent/child? I was found http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ for anysnchronius saving but there is not code example.

Comment: Marcus can you please help me and answer at question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024859/core-data-child-parent-save-exception ? i was post there own answer, but problem still here and i have no idea how i can debug it.

Comment: hi Marcus. I try to implement async save on osx but got freezing main queue. Please help tp answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314599/parent-child-moc-with-async-disc-saving-got-freeze-main-queue-on-osx