# core data child/parent save exception

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I got crash (probably while parent moc saved:

this is how moc's created (parent):

```
   if (_managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation) return _managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinatorInMemoryForDynamicInformation];
    if (!coordinator) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:@"Failed to initialize the store" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [dict setValue:@"There was an error building up the data file." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    [_managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation setUndoManager:nil];
    return _managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation;
```

child:

```
    AppDelegate *delegateMain = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation setUndoManager:nil];
    _mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation.parentContext = delegateMain.managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation;
```

this is how i save:

```
-(void) finalSaveMocInMemoryForDynamicInformation;
{
    [_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation performBlock:^{
        // do something that takes some time asynchronously using the temp context

        // push to parent
        NSError *error;
        if ([_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation save:&error])
        {
            AppDelegate *delegateMain = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            // save parent to disk asynchronously
            [delegateMain.managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation performBlock:^{
                @try {
                    NSError *error;
                    if (![delegateMain.managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation save:&error])
                    {
                        [self logError:error];
                    }
                }
                @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR:%@:%@ exception->%@ inside managedObjectContextInMemoryForDynamicInformation",[self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),exception);
                    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:moc];

                    return ;
                }

            }];
        } else [self logError:error];
    }];
}
```

> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a
>   fault for '0x7fd8a71d87a0
>   ''
>   abort() called terminate called throwing an exception
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff86e6f0a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff849353f0 objc_exception_throw + 43 2   CoreData
>   0x00007fff8737eec4 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1348 3   CoreData
>   0x00007fff8737e61f _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 239 4   CoreData
>   0x00007fff873892cd _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex + 77 5
>   CoreData                            0x00007fff8738cc51
>   _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 129 6   CoreData                            0x00007fff873a4eaa -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods)
>   _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1434 7   Foundation                          0x00007fff878fe860
>   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 390 8   Foundation
>   0x00007fff87900279 NSKeyValueDidChange + 456 9   Foundation
>   0x00007fff878bb7df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification)
>   didChangeValueForKey:] + 130 10  CoreData
>   0x00007fff873898c1 -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 113 11 
>   CoreData                            0x00007fff873e566d
>   -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:] + 685 12  CoreData                            0x00007fff873b0969 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
>   _copyChildObject:toParentObject:fromChildContext:] + 121 13  CoreData                            0x00007fff873b0505 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
>   _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 629 14  CoreData                            0x00007fff873df72a __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport)
>   executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 634 15 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8aad6a2d
>   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 77 16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8aad10b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 17  libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x00007fff8aad60c8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 275 18 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86e110fe __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 1614 19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86e106b2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 20  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff89d950a4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209 21  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff89d94e42 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356 22  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff89d94cd3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62 23 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8ffcd613 _DPSNextEvent +
>   685 24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ffcced2
>   -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128 25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ffc4283
>   -[NSApplication run] + 517 26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8ff68cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869 27  callsfreecall
>   0x000000010e6ab472 main + 34 28  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff858a47e1 start + 0 29  ???
>   0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I found solution of that crash.

A crash was passed in that code:

```
    [_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[session] error:&error];
```

This is know bug in apple, where I can't get permanent Id. If I try to do it on child context, save is product that crash.

This is how I solve it:

```
    [_mocInMemoryForDynamicInformation.parentContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[session] error:&error];
```

This simple solution solve all issues (I can't explain how but this is work).

Comment: Warning: in my case, this "fix" instead caused tons of other new issues for me! (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Answer (score 1):

Your var identifiers are really confusing. Names like parentContext, child Context, rootContext and so on are to tricky?

Anyway, the problem is probably not the save operation. On a first view it looks like you changed a relationship of an object to another object, but the other object does not exist any more. This can happen, if the other object is faulted into the child context and deleted in the store. (Probably because the parent context deleted the object and saved its state.)

Comment: those names more comfortable for me to remember complicated logic. Regarding you answer - i understand what u write, but how i can avoid that or debug that? My model means that all relationships must deleted when head object deleted, but here i can't debug that crash, it's in main queue and i have no idea how to get source of bug...