# parent/child MOC with async disc saving got freeze main queue on osx

Tags: macos, core-data

I have currently try to implement scheme:

MOC1 (PrivateQueue) -parent-> MOC2 (MainQueue) -parent-> MOC3 (PrivateQueue), PSC to save

here is init code (MOC2 & MOC#:

```
_writeManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
_writeManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
_writeManagedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;

_mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
_mainManagedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;
_mainManagedObjectContext.parentContext = _writeManagedObjectContext;
```

Here is init MOC1:

```
    _mocSSchild = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    _mocSSchild.undoManager = nil;
    _mocSSchild.parentContext = delegateMain.mainManagedObjectContext;
```

Here is a save:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.mocSSchild obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:self.mocSSchild.insertedObjects.allObjects error:&error];

    if (![self.mocSSchild save: &error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save to FIRST data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0)
    {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors)
        {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
    }

    }
    AppDelegate *delegateMain = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegateMain.mainManagedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![delegateMain.mainManagedObjectContext save: &error]) {        NSLog(@"Failed to save to FIRST data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0)
    {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors)
        {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
}
    if ([delegateMain.writeManagedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![delegateMain.writeManagedObjectContext save: &error]) {        NSLog(@"Failed to save to FIRST data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0)
    {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors)
        {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

All fetch requests is placed in right block (and of course i never touch mainManagedObjectContext to execute fetch requests):

```
    __block NSError *error = nil;
    __block NSArray *findedResult = nil;
    [self.mocSSchild performBlockAndWait:^{
        findedResult = [self.mocSSchild executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];
```

After one save i have freezing in main queue (looks like core data try to execute fetch request on mainManagedObjectContext where i don't do requests):

```
Call graph:
    2633 Thread_803320   DispatchQueue_173: NSManagedObjectContext Queue  (serial)
    + 2633 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff8bb907e1]
    +   2633 main  (in callsfreecall) + 34  [0x10992c202]
    +     2633 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 869  [0x7fff8a49cbd6]
    +       2633 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 517  [0x7fff8a4f81a3]
    +         2633 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]  (in AppKit) + 128  [0x7fff8a500df2]
    +           2633 _DPSNextEvent  (in AppKit) + 685  [0x7fff8a501533]
    +             2633 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 62  [0x7fff8f356ae3]
    +               2633 ReceiveNextEventCommon  (in HIToolbox) + 356  [0x7fff8f356c52]
    +                 2633 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode  (in HIToolbox) + 209  [0x7fff8f356eb4]
    +                   2633 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 290  [0x7fff9526c0e2]
    +                     2633 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1644  [0x7fff9526cb4c]
    +                       2633 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 275  [0x7fff8c4c20c8]
    +                         2633 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff8c4bd0b6]
    +                           2633 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff8c4c2a2d]
    +                             2633 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0  (in CoreData) + 533  [0x7fff93d8b6c5]
    +                               2633 -[NSManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:error:]  (in CoreData) + 1563  [0x7fff93d65ddb]
    +                                 2633 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _countWithNoChangesForRequest:error:]  (in CoreData) + 298  [0x7fff93d65f4a]
    +                                   2633 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]  (in CoreData) + 354  [0x7fff93d576c2]
    +                                     2633 _perform  (in CoreData) + 172  [0x7fff93d5787c]
    +                                       2633 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff8c4be723]
    +                                         2633 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff8c4bd0b6]
    +                                           2633 __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0  (in CoreData) + 533  [0x7fff93d8b6c5]
    +                                             2633 -[NSManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:error:]  (in CoreData) + 1563  [0x7fff93d65ddb]
    +                                               2633 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _countWithNoChangesForRequest:error:]  (in CoreData) + 298  [0x7fff93d65f4a]
    +                                                 2633 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]  (in CoreData) + 1138  [0x7fff93d10ba2]
    +                                                   2633 -[_PFLock lock]  (in CoreData) + 24  [0x7fff93cfe548]
    +                                                     2633 pthread_mutex_lock  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 536  [0x7fff92797dfd]
    +                                                       2633 __psynch_mutexwait  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff938ca122]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to do something with errors when you receive them.  Right now you are not doing anything, not logging them, not reacting to them, nothing.  This is bad.  When an error occurs you have no indication of it at all.  You just go onto the next step.

Second, you are saving all of your MOCs on the same queue.  Any activity against a private MOC must be performed inside of a block via the `-performBlock:` or `-performBlockAndWait:` methods.

Third, there is no indication what queue you are running on.

Your import MOC should be running inside of an operation or a block running async.  The import MOC should be using thread confinement instead of being a private MOC.  Once the import MOC has completed its work it should save itself and then indicate to the main queue that the main MOC should be saved.

The main MOC should only be saved on the main queue.  When the main MOC has completed its save then it should fire off a save to the top level MOC via its `-performBlock:`.

Correct your issues with the error results and take a look at what queues you are doing the work on.  If everything is on the main queue then parent/child MOCs is not going to solve your problem.  You need to rethink what work is being performed where.

### Update 1

First, you can detect the errors by listening to the results from the calls.  If the call returns a `BOOL` then that is a pass/fail.  If the call returns something else then if that something else is `nil` then that is a failure and the error will be present.

As for your code, no it is not correct.  You have threading issues as I mentioned.  You are touching a private MOC directly, that is incorrect.  There are probably other errors but I cannot see them based on this code.

Your "writing" MOC should only be touched via a `-performBlock:` or `-performBlockAndWait:`. In this case you should be using a `-performBlock:`.  You are touching it directly.  That is bad.

Your main MOC should only be touched on the main queue or via a `-performBlock:`/`-performBlockAndWait:`.  You appear to be touching it directly in this code.

You are accessing your `appDelegate` as a singleton.  This is a bad code smell.  Look up and start using dependency injection.

Your child moc is set up as a private when it should be a thread confined context and then it should only be accessed on the thread that created it which ideally should be in an NSOperation.

In short, there is a lot of core concepts that you are missing here.  You need to understand how parent/child contexts work and you need to have a better understanding of queues and threads before you attempt to develop code like this.

Comment: 1. i was updated question, of course i get errors 2. It functions called from background thread, so it called only for local copy owned for my class object. It not called for all created MOCs, but i will try to using performBlock for save. But is my code ok?: __block NSArray *findedResult = nil;
    [self.mocSSchild performBlockAndWait:^{
        findedResult = [self.mocSSchild executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];

Comment: "Correct your issues with the error results and take a look at what queues you are doing the work on." - how i can detect it? A freeze which i see, is in main thread. Backtrace showing me that execute fetch request starting on mainQueue MOC. But i don't call mainMOC execute fetch request. This is where i'm confused.